# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_inactive' not found. 'account_inactive' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-auth

I am using `django-rest-auth` registration api, I overridden that by using my own `SERIALIZER` and model. So I am getting error.

I have tried by setting active at the time user created. But that is not working.

Let me know how to resolve this type of problem.

````
[12/Jan/2019 17:24:06] "POST /rest-auth/registration/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68
Internal Server Error: /rest-auth/registration/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 46, in dispatch
    return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 65, in create
    user = self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 81, in perform_create
    None)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 183, in complete_signup
    signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 133, in perform_login
    return adapter.respond_user_inactive(request, user)
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 454, in respond_user_inactive
    reverse('account_inactive'))
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/test/project/vblah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_inactive' not found. 'account_inactive' is not a valid view function or pattern name.```
````

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please post your actual code.  the stack trace is not going to help anyone fix your problem

Comment: Please add your urls.py and view.py

Comment: @SergeyPugach here's mine.
views.py is empty, urls.py is simply this:
```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

this exception happend because  in your User model
is_active = False .
so set True and migrate

in models.py set `is_active = True`
and migrate the tables

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.